# How do I determine if a NSFont is installed on a Mac OSX machine in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, fonts

Is there a method to check if a NSFont with string name is installed by the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if it's present in this array:

```
NSArray *fonts = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies];
```

by calling

```
[fonts containsObject:@"Times"];
```

`containsObject` uses the `isEqual:` method to compare two objects. Because you know that every object in the `fonts` array is an `NSString`, you know that you'll get a `YES` if the array contains `@"Times"`, and a `NO` if it doesn't.

Comment: How would I go about checking through the array? Would I have to use a for statement?

Comment: Sorry about that, just added a clarification in the answer body.

Comment: that is not completely correct, as you are checking the font family, not the font... note that the font family might have different fonts (styles), like Bold, Italic and let's say Bold might not have been installed

Comment: How can I do this with swift?

Comment: In swift, something like this will do the trick: NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers( "Times" )

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html

for finding the font family (which  might consist of several fonts (style)

```
NSFontDescriptor *helveticaNeueFamily =
    [NSFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:
        @{ NSFontFamilyAttribute: @"Helvetica Neue" }];
NSArray *matches =
    [helveticaNeueFamily matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys: nil];
```

and then you can check also for Bold, italic, etc (exact name)

```
NSFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor =
    [NSFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:
        @{ NSFontNameAttribute: @"Bank Gothic Medium" }];
NSArray *matches =
    [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys: nil];
```

like

```
- (BOOL)isFontNameInstalledInSystem {

    if (self.fontName == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [NSFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:@{NSFontNameAttribute:self.fontName}];
    NSArray *matches = [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys: nil];

    return ([matches count] > 0);
}
```

you might also want to use (But be sure to have the font name in right format)
note that this i a bit more resource intensive

```
- (BOOL)isFontNameInstalledInSystem {
    return ([NSFont fontWithName:self.fontName size:[NSFont systemFontSize]]) != nil;
}
```